# cakephp group by with n result for each group

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I need to extract 3 result from each category in a database using cakephp, I tried to query in database using mysql session variable and conditions as below

```
    SELECT *, @question_cat_rank := 0, @question_cat_country:=''
   FROM
     (SELECT *, 
                  @question_cat_rank := IF(@question_cat_country = question_setname.question_cat, @question_cat_rank + 1, 1) AS question_cat_rank,
                  @question_cat_country := question_cat 
       FROM question_setname
        ORDER BY question_cat desc
     ) ranked
   WHERE question_cat_rank <= 3
```

its working fine in mysql query analyzer but when i query using cakephp its returning all results in table instaed of 3 results

i tried to create it using cakephp way like below

```
public $virtualFields = array(
                '@catvirt' => 1,
                '@catvirt2' => 'question_cat',
                'incrmt' => 'IF(@catvirt2 = question_cat, @catvirt+1, 1)',
            );
        function getquestionGroup(){

            $result1 = $this->find('all', array(
                'fields' => array('question_cat', '@catvirt2', 'incrmt'),
                '@catvirt2'=> 'question_cat',
                '@catvirt' => '@catvirt'
                    )
                  );

            $result = $this->find('all', array($result1,
                'conditions' => array('@catvirt <=' => 3), 
                    )
                  );
```

i tried to execute as prepared statementand stored procedure also still no luck its returning all results

any help will be appreciated

Comment: I've never thought to initalise the variables except within a subquery. Does it work this way??

Comment: yes it works i tried by removing initializing part also but still same

Comment: It doesn't work in my tests - but maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

I would write that query this way:

```
 SELECT x.* 
   FROM           
      ( SELECT *                                             
             , @question_cat_rank := IF(@question_cat_country = question_cat, @question_cat_rank + 1, 1) question_cat_rank
             , @question_cat_country := question_cat 
          FROM question_setname 
             , (SELECT @question_cat_rank := 0, @question_cat_country:='') vars
         ORDER 
            BY question_cat DESC
      ) x
  WHERE question_cat_rank <= 3;
```